# Reading Multiple Files in Spark and Processing it before Appending

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My problem is I've multiple txt files of identical  structure, which I want to import into spark. Then create an identifier column, summarize the data and finally stacking them.

E.g. one of the file looks like the following:

```
   Date     A   B   C
2/21/2014   A1  11  2
2/22/2014   A1  11  5
2/23/2014   A1  21  3
2/24/2014   A1  13  5
2/25/2014   A1  23  4
2/26/2014   A1  28  4
2/27/2014   A1  32  2
2/28/2014   B1  45  4
3/1/2014    B1  39  4
3/2/2014    B1  29  4
3/3/2014    B1  49  5
3/4/2014    B1  18  4
3/5/2014    B1  30  3
3/6/2014    B1  50  5
```

After reading this file, I want to add a column mentioning file name and the updated data look like this:

```
    Date    A   B   C   File
2/21/2014   A1  22  2   File1
2/22/2014   A1  36  2   File1
2/23/2014   A1  17  4   File1
2/24/2014   A1  30  2   File1
2/25/2014   A1  11  2   File1
2/26/2014   A1  32  2   File1
2/27/2014   A1  19  5   File1
2/28/2014   B1  22  3   File1
3/1/2014    B1  12  5   File1
3/2/2014    B1  50  3   File1
3/3/2014    B1  42  4   File1
3/4/2014    B1  37  4   File1
3/5/2014    B1  31  5   File1
3/6/2014    B1  20  3   File1
```

And then summarize the data:

```
 File   A   B   C
File1   A1  167 19
File1   B1  214 27
```

Similary, another dataset will be created and summarized. Finally stacked together. IN case of 2 files the datasets look like this:

```
File    A   B   C
File1   A1  167 19
File1   B1  214 27
File2   Z10 167 19
File2   X20 214 27
```

I can individually import the data, process them by converting it into dataframe and then finally stack them. But I could not able to do it in automated fashion. Can anyone please help me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: did you try any piece of the logic?

Comment: @WoodChopper: Thanks for you comment. For automation,no. But I read the data, converted into sql dataframe, added the new column with file name. If you want I can put the codes I used so far in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your single file fits into memory you can use `wholeTextFiles`,

```
rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("/directorypath/*")

def appender(x):
    i = x[0]
    j = x[1].split("\n")
    k = [x.split() for x in j]
    l = [x.append(i) for x in k]
    return k

frdd = rdd.flatMap(appender)

df = frdd.toDF("Date","A","B","C","FileName")
```

`wholeTextFiles` returns tuple of (file name, content of the file) from there you can append the file name.

```
df.groupBy("FileName","A").count() ##sum()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This was really helpful!